# getting a java.Lang.NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION at line "ParseDocument(doc)" and "Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();"

Tags: java, android

here i am just trying to parse an xml file and store the contents in an array lists, but everytime its giving java.Lang.NullPointerException at two points, pls help in debugging this...

```
public class XML_PARSER extends Activity {

String TAG= "XML_PARSER";
List optionList = new ArrayList(); 
Document dom;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parser);



    Document doc=parseXmlFile();
```

at this line it is giving a java null pointer exception

```
    ParseDocument(doc); 

    //printData();


}
private Document parseXmlFile(){
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        dom=db.parse("R.raw.options.xml");

    }

    catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SAXException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dom;

}


private void ParseDocument(Document dom){
```

at this lineits giving the same error

```
    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
    Node node;

    NodeList n1= docEle.getElementsByTagName("Option");
    if(n1!=null && n1.getLength()>0){
        for(int i=0;i<n1.getLength();i++){
            node=n1.item(i);

            Element e1=(Element)n1.item(i);

            Option e = getOption(e1,node);

            optionList.add(e);

            }

        }
    }
```

here is the log cat for the same

```
07-20 12:21:48.391: E/AndroidRuntime(836): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 12:21:48.391: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.example.xml_parser.XML_PARSER.ParseDocument(XML_PARSER.java:67)

07-20 12:21:48.391: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.example.xml_parser.XML_PARSER.onCreate(XML_PARSER.java:38)

07-20 12:21:48.391: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)

07-20 12:21:48.391: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)

07-20 12:21:48.391: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted the LogCat error trace and only the code around the error. It's too much code to look through.

Comment: done tht, now pls help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `R.raw.options.xml` is not a valid URI so in this line `dom=db.parse("R.raw.options.xml");`, the `dom` variable is null. You are trying to use methods of the null variable `doc` (line `Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();` inside the `ParseDocument(doc);` method), that is why you get a `NullPointerException`. If you pass a valid URI in `dom=db.parse("valid_URI");` method you will eliminate the two`NullPointerExceptions`.

**EDIT** Here is a complete example:

```
private Document parseXmlFile(){
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
       DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
       Resources res = getResources();
       InputStream in = res.openRawResource(R.raw.options);
       dom=db.parse(in); //Here instead of passing the URI string, you pass the input stream of the file.

    }

    catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SAXException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dom;

}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i thought the same thing, but i didn't know what will be the right path for my file residing in my raw folder under res... can u pls tell me what will the correct path..

Comment: i m still not getting it....see i need a string URI for my db.parse()..  tht is not what i m getting in the link given...i m new to all this so require a lil bit more help...